# HTML5/JS Chart with Moving Average

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

**Question:** How can a moving average line be calculated and plotted on a JS/HTML5 chart?

The closest example I can find is [this website](http://bitcoinwisdom.com/). Looking at its JS files, I cannot identify the plotting chart library. Upon closer inspection, it appears that the moving average was not calculated on the serverside but not the clientside.

Any suggestions appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Unable to get that page to load any charts. For highcharts, at least, you would need to calculate it yourself behind the scene and add to the chart when you add the other points.

Comment: Are you referring to calculating a running N-point mean?  Why are you looking for a library to do this, should be dead simple client or server side and then it's just another series for highcharts to draw.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/vy4C3/) which calculates a 3-point moving average client side and plots it with Highcharts:

```
var N = 100;
var someData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    someData.push([i,Math.random() * 100]);
}

var moveMean = [];
for (var i = 1; i < N-1; i++)
{
    var mean = (someData[i][1] + someData[i-1][1] + someData[i+1][1])/3.0;
    moveMean.push([i,mean]);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a more general purpose function below.

To use it, simply pass an array of values, the count (or length) of the moving average, and an optional qualifier function.

For example:

`movingAvg(arr, 10)` will return a 10 data point moving average of the values in the array `arr`.

`movingAvg(arr, 20, function(val){ return val != 0; })` will return a 20 data point moving average of the non-zero values in the array `arr`

So with Chart.js, for example, you can use it like so:

```
...
,datasets: [
     {
         label: "Values"
        ,data: values
    }
    ,{
         type: "line"
        ,label: "20 Point Moving Average"
        ,data: movingAvg(values, 20, function(val){ return val != 0; })
    }
]
...
```

The function:

```
    /**
    * returns an array with moving average of the input array
    * @param array - the input array
    * @param count - the number of elements to include in the moving average calculation
    * @param qualifier - an optional function that will be called on each 
    *  value to determine whether it should be used
    */
    function movingAvg(array, count, qualifier){

        // calculate average for subarray
        var avg = function(array, qualifier){

            var sum = 0, count = 0, val;
            for (var i in array){
                val = array[i];
                if (!qualifier || qualifier(val)){
                    sum += val;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return sum / count;
        };

        var result = [], val;

        // pad beginning of result with null values
        for (var i=0; i < count-1; i++)
            result.push(null);

        // calculate average for each subarray and add to result
        for (var i=0, len=array.length - count; i <= len; i++){

            val = avg(array.slice(i, i + count), qualifier);
            if (isNaN(val))
                result.push(null);
            else
                result.push(val);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: This is a standard moving average which results in a delay (or lag) being introduced to your results. If you wish to avoid this, use a symmetrical moving average such as in @Mark's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A more general and simple function would be this one:

```js
function movingAvg(array, countBefore, countAfter) {
  if (countAfter == undefined) countAfter = 0;
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const subArr = array.slice(Math.max(i - countBefore, 0), Math.min(i + countAfter + 1, array.length));
    const avg = subArr.reduce((a, b) => a + (isNaN(b) ? 0 : b), 0) / subArr.length;
    result.push(avg);
  }
  return result;
}

const myArr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

//averages of 7 (i.e. 7 day moving average):
const avg7Before = movingAvg(myArr, 6); //6 before and the current
const avg7Middle = movingAvg(myArr, 3, 3); //3 before, 3 after, plus the current
const avg7After = movingAvg(myArr, 0, 6); //6 after plus the current


console.log('original:',...myArr.map(x => x.toFixed(1)));
console.log('7 before:',...avg7Before.map(x => x.toFixed(1)));
console.log('7 middle:',...avg7Middle.map(x => x.toFixed(1)));
console.log('7 after: ',...avg7After.map(x => x.toFixed(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I  came across the same issue. 
Here is my example for your reference. 
You can set any length of sample point as you want.

```js
var getAverage = function(arr, n){
  var sum=0;
  if(n>arr.length){
    n = arr.length;
  }
  
  for(var ii=arr.length-n; ii<arr.length; ii++){
    sum += arr[ii];
  }
  return sum/n;
}


function(acceleration, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not mine but it works very well for moving averages in Financial calculations.

```
var movingAverage = function(d, t, roundUp) {
    if (d.length >= t && d.constructor === Array) {
        var r = [], s = 0, f = this.decimalRoundingFactor, ma;

        roundUp = typeof roundUp === undefined? true : roundUp;

        for(var i=0;i<d.length;++i) {
            s += isNaN(d[i])? 0: d[i];
            if (i < t-1) {
                r.push(NaN);
            } else if (i+1 === t) {
                ma = roundUp? Math.round((s/t)*f)/f: s/t;
                r.push(ma);
            } else {
                s -= isNaN(d[i-t])? 0: d[i-t];
                ma = roundUp? Math.round((s/t)*f)/f: s/t;
                r.push(ma);
            }
        }

        return r;
    } else {
        throw "[ERROR] TechnicalAnalysis#movingAverage: Not enought data! OR data is not Array!";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit old by now, but maybe this will help someone.

```js
function sma(tIndex, N, array) {
    // return undefined if array is falsy, if range lookback or N exceeds array length
    if (!array || (tIndex - N) < 0 || N > array.length) return;
    const range = array.slice((tIndex - N), tIndex);
    const sum = range.reduce((acc, num) => acc += num, 0);
    return (sum / N);
}
```

Where: tIndex = "current price index", N = "lookback range", array = "Dataset"